# Get Updated HTML String After Clone with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, clone

I'm building an application which has a D&D editor and deal with layouts (based on bootstrap) and multiple widgets.

Each widget has various parameters which are editable with a modal after clicking on the corresponding widget edit link.

I pass in the html generating the form elements for these params, base64 encoded through a data attribute like this:

```
<a href="#" class="edit-widget" data-tabgeneral="<?php echo $tab_general; ?>" data-tabstyle="<?php echo $tab_style; ?>">Edit</a>
```

I grab that string, decode it and append it to the modal box which spits out the form.  This all works perfectly fine.  As a sidenote, before I was just spitting out the form elements in a hidden div within each widget container, then grabbing it from there.  The result was 75K elements in dom with a very few number of widgets and a 3 second delay on any click event, plus a generally sluggish interface (as you can imagine).

Upon clicking the save button for the widget, I need to get the html of the form elements that were appended to the modal WITH the updated values, encode it and update the widget data attribute with the new string.

That part works fine, but what doesn't is upon clicking the save button, it clones the modal form elements.  That object which contains the originally appended form markup has the correct, updated values for each form element.

For example:

```
    var tab_general = $('#modal-widget-CSS-Params-tab_general');
    var test_update_value = tab_general.find('input[name="widget-videofakeout[1371898762][content]"]').val();
    console.log(test_update_value);
```

The result is the proper updated value, so I know the it has the proper data that I want inside.

But if I create a new dom element with the by cloning this object and attempt to use jQuery's html method to get the new, updated html string of said clone, like so:

```
console.log($('<div>').append(tab_general.clone(true, true)).remove().html());
```

All I get is the original appended html with the original input values.

So my question is, is there any way to get the html string of a cloned object with the updated input values?  Or am I going about this all wrong?

Here's a very basic example of what I'm trying to do, but as per the first comment below, it seems I'm totally off-base: http://jsfiddle.net/6LyMK/2/

Comment: User changes to inputs are not in the DOM.

Comment: Hey thanks, so it appears I'm going about this the wrong way.  What would be the best way then to generate the updated html string of the object with the user changes intact?  Convert it to a dom element, would that work?

Comment: Iterate through all the input elements, and do something like `$(this).attr('value', $(this).val())`.

Comment: I guess I'm not following. The object already contains the proper updated values.  I need to get that into an html string with the update values intact within the string.  Also, I need to retain all the extra stuff (all elements within the object, not just the input elements) and convert it all to a resulting html string.  Hope I'm making sense.  Thanks...

Comment: How did the object get the proper updated values? I thought you were talking about the values that the user entered when filling in the form. Those are returned by `.val()`, but they're not part of the HTML.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the responses.  I put together the example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6LyMK/2/  -- the problem comes at lines 22 and 23.  Click edit widget, then change the text input, then click save widget.  The first alert confirms the object has the proper updated data.  The second alert shows the html string for the object with the original data.  I've tried several things, just can't figure out how to get the updated string.  Not even sure if I'm on the right track here.

Comment: Ah... Thanks a lot.  Must be tired.  Just now understood what you meant with your previous comment. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/6LyMK/4/ - needed to set the user changes into dom as you said, by iterating through (lines 15-19).  Thanks again.  Kind of new here.  I'd like to give you credit for the answer.  How do I do that?